# phpslim v3, check if named route exists

Tags: php, slim

How can I check if a named route exists in phpslim v3?
I cannot seem to do a try/catch on a name that does not exist, execution still exists with an error.

```
try {
    $redirect_to = $this->router->pathFor($dynamic);
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    $redirect_to = $this->router->pathFor('dashboard');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    $this->router->getNamedRoute($dynamic);
    echo "Route found.";
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
    echo "Route not found!";
}
```

See: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Router.php#L268

Comment: Thank you! Worked great. Just two small changes
$this-router for $this->router
and
RuntimeException $e for \RuntimeException $e